# Get nsIX509CertDB importCertsFromFile failure reason?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

When I use the `importCertsFromFile()` method of the `nsIX509CertDB` interface component, Any failure seems to throw the same exception:

```
Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIX509CertDB.importCertsFromFile]
```

Is there any way to determine the reason for failure?

Sometime, it shows an alert with the reason, like "that certificate is already installed". Sometimes it just throws the exception without any built-in alert,such as choosing a word document or any non=certificate file.

```
certdb = components.classes[nsX509CertDB].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIX509CertDB);   

try{
   certdb.importCertsFromFile(null, fp.file, nsIX509Cert.CA_CERT);
   alert('The certificate was added succesfully!');
}catch(e){
   alert(e);
}
```

I would like to determine the reason for the failure, so I can show a proper error message, if the component doesn't already have an error for that case. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way the XPCOM wrappers to NSS and most of NSS is implemented, there isn't really any way to get more detailed errors than those exceptions. You can see for yourself: [The code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/ssl/src/nsNSSCertificateDB.cpp#1041) is riddled with `NS_ERROR_FAILURE` returns (which get translated in the Javascript exceptions by the XPConnect bridge), but really nothing more. Also, the [NSS status codes](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/nss/lib/util/seccomon.h#63) aren't really detailed to begin with.

So expect to get the non-descriptive `NS_ERROR_FAILURE` most of the time, with some `NS_ERROR_FILE_*` exception added to the mix once in a while if the file isn't accessible.

Comment: That's certainly unfortunate. The best we can do then is say, "something went wrong. You may (or may not) have received a reason. If you did not receive a reason, there is no reason available. Please try again."